# Can multiple string variables really refer to the same data?

Tags: string, delphi, reference-counting

According to the information in the internet I found out that two following variables
point to the same place in memory.

Could anyone propose a code example to demonstrate that in fact it is true (e.g. by changing one of the letter in the 1st variable and see that this change is visible from the second variable)?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b: String;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;

  showmessage (a);
  showmessage (b);
end;
```

Comment: It's true for dynamic arrays too. What's different is that strings implement copy on write but strings don't.

Comment: @Paul, your title sounds like your question is related to reference counting, but your question test is about variables pointing to the same address... I think you shall find a better title and edit the question.

Comment: I think that the The title is appropriate as in my code example assigning variable causes reference incrementing.

Comment: `a := 'Test'; b := 'Test';` results in `a` and `b` having different storage addresses.

Comment: Really, @David? It shouldn't. Those should both refer to the same literal, and should both have a reference count of -1.

Comment: @David, @Rob: I just tested it. Rob is right and David is wrong (sorry!).

Comment: @Jachguate, if you don't like a title, you can edit it to make it better. Its *encouraged*, even.

Comment: OK fair enough, I didn't think it through. How about this one though, `a := 'Test'; b := 'Te'+'st';` These will have different addresses. Or my previous example but the two assignments written in different procedures.

Comment: @Rob I do it sometimes.. this one I just didn't get a suitable title in two or three time-slices, and I think it should be encouraged to educate people to find good titles by themselves also. :)

Comment: @David: Same constant assigned to variables in different procedures would point to the same address, unless in D2009+ the variables are of different string types as Delphi generates constant values with different encodings based on the use of the constant. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292611/is-there-some-advantage-in-use-resourcestring-instead-of-a-const-string/4293415#4293415 for how Delphi stores resource strings and string consts.

Comment: @marjan and literals? Compiler won't hunt down duplicates of those surely?

Comment: @David: I think it does. I will check to make sure, but that will have to wait until after my running training... :-)

Comment: @David: Compiler de-dupes string literals within the same method, but you are right it doesn't de-dupe across methods.

Comment: @marjan across unit de-dupe would require second pass

Comment: @David, @Rob: doing a := TEST_CONST; and b:= TEST_CONST; does pull the the value from the same address, but results in two copies in memory with different storage addresses. Behind the scenes, Delphi is doing a UniqueStringU (not the exact name) call, whereas it did not use to do that pre D2009. Checked it in both D2009/D2010. Don't know whether this is still the case in XE (don't have it available). After the assignment, reference counting and copy-on-write do kick in. Should be the same for string literals. @Andreas: With which version of Delphi did you check @David's statement?

Comment: @Marjan @Rob @Andreas Writeable typed const? Even if you don't have it on, the compiler maybe handles consts under the assumption that you might.

Comment: @David, @Rob, @Andreas: Assignalble typed const was off when I checked earlier. Turning it on didn't make a difference...

Comment: @marjan was your constant typed?

Comment: @David: It was untyped. But making it typed (`TEST_CONST: string = 'Test'`) makes no difference. Tried all 4 combinations of typed/untyped and assignable/non-assignable. UniqueStringU keeps getting called...

Comment: @Marjan I can't reproduce your reported findings!

Comment: @David: Let's get off this comment trail. I will send you my test project by mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  a, b: string;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  a := a + '!'; // added after Rob's comment below, 
                // makes sure a points to an allocation on the heap
  b := a;
  PChar(b)[3] := 'T';
  ShowMessage(a); //--> TesT!
end;
```

Comment: +1 This was already answered, but your answer shows a nice way to see it really points to the same data, not just by using pointers, but the data. :)

Comment: If this really behaves the way you say it does, then it's a remarkable demonstration. It either shows that the compiler knows that the string in `a` will be modified via `b` and therefore assigns a writable string instead of a literal (which is a feat of static analysis I don't associate with Delphi), or it shows that literals aren't stored in read-only memory with the rest of the program's data.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, you are right, the above might crash. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 8):

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b: string;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(pointer(a) = pointer(b), true));
end;
```

The result is `True`, so yes, `a` and `b` point to the same data.

Notice, however, that

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b: string;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;
  b := 'Test2';
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(pointer(a) = pointer(b), true));
end;
```

displays `False`, as it should be.

In addition, notice that

```
procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  a, b: string;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;
  ShowMessage(BoolToStr(@a = @b, true));
end;
```

also displays `False`, because `a` and `b` are *different* string (pointer) variables, so at some place in memory (`@a`) is the address of the data of `a`, and somewhere else (`@b`) is the address of the data of `b`. The first example shows that these two places in memory contain the same address, that is, that `a` and `b` contain the same data.

Comment: Well, thanks, but can you propose an example to change the content one of these two variable?

Answer (score 3):

Normally Delphi use 'copy-on-write' semantics for strings, so you need a kind of hacking to do the trick, for example:

```
procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Test: string = '12345';

var
  S1, S2: string;
  P: PChar;

begin
  SetString(S1, PChar(Test), 5);
// we need to copy '12345' string from readonly memory to heap
  S2:= S1;
// Now both S1 and S2 points to the same memory

  P:= Pointer(S1);
  P^:= 'A';
  ShowMessage(S2);  // 'A2345'
end;
```

Comment: If you do this for real in some production code, and you work with me, I leave a rotten Herring carcase on your desk.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear for me.
If you do :

```
begin 
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;
  a := a+'HH';
  showmessage (a);
  showmessage (b); 
end;
```

I think you will see it...

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question. My first block of code demonstrates that `a` and `b` point to the same data if you skip the `a := a+'HH';` line in your code.

Comment: Yes I had misunderstood it..and make another answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK may be more clear with this code

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

var
  a, b , s : string;
  p : pointer;
begin
  a := 'Test';
  b := a;
// we see the 2 diff. var pointing on the same adress
  s := Format('%p -> %p / %p -> %p', [@pointer(a),pointer(a),@pointer(b),pointer(b)] );
  ShowMessage( 'first : '+s);
// we see the 2 diff. var pointing on different adresses
  a := 'Test2';
  s := Format('%p -> %p / %p -> %p', [@pointer(a),pointer(a),@pointer(b),pointer(b)] );
  ShowMessage( 'second : '+s);
end;
```