# How to translate (internationalize, localize) application?

Tags: delphi, localization, internationalization

I need to translate an application on delphi. Now all strings in interface on Russian. 
What are the tools for fast find, parcing all pas'es for string constants?

How people translate large applications?

Comment: one more Home-brew solution was listed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456480

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GetText should be able to do, search for "extract" at http://dxgettext.po.dk/documentation/how-to

---

If all you need is to translate GUI and maybe *resourcestring* in sources, and the inline string constants in Pascal sources are not needed for translation, then you can try Delphi built-in method. However forums say that ITE is buggy. But at least that is official Delphi way.

- http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32974
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Creating_Resource_DLLs

To translate sources with ITM manual preparation is needed as shown in source sheets at http://www.gunsmoker.ru/2010/06/delphi-ite-integrated-translation.html

---

I remember i tranlsated Polaris texts for JediVCL team - so they did some extraction. But i think they just extracted all characters > #127 into a text file - there was no structure, there were constants and comments, all together.
Still, there is some component, though i doubt it can be used the way you need: http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvTranslator

---

There are also commercial tools. But i don't know if their features would help you on your initial extraction and translation tasks. They probably would be of much help when you need to mantain your large application translated to many languages, but not when you need to do one-time conversion. But maybe i am wrong, check their trial versions if you wish. By reviews those suites are considered among best of commercial ones:

- TsiLang Suite http://www.tsilang.com/?siteid2=7
- Korzh Localizer http://devtools.korzh.com/localization-delphi/

Comment: FWIW: dxgettext doesn't seem to be maintained. Doesn't work in Tokyo. Links on website are broken; link to svn repo is broken too. I don't think I would use it in a project I start today.

Comment: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456480  linked above a compilable copy of GetText is included in JediVCL. Though this "cemetery of abandoned libraries" might see little mantainance today as well. Anyway, when you "start new project" you have a choice to invent your own wheel, to buy commercial library and hope on their support, to pick up someone's FLOSS work and update it. If i would start a new project i would consider taking dxGetText and trying it. Maybe fixing it would be easy. If not - then reinventing a wheel i still would look into their sources for lessons and hints

Answer (score 5):

Firstly I'd recommend to move all localizable string constants into the resource string sections within their unit files. I.e.

```
raise Exception.Create('Error: что-то пошло не так (in Russian language)');
```

will be converted to

```
resourcestring
  rsSomeErrorMessage = 'Error: что-то пошло не так (in Russian language)';
...
raise Exception.Create(rsSomeErrorMessage);
```

[More about Resource Strings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4292611/is-there-some-advantage-in-use-resourcestring-instead-of-a-const-string)

This process can be accelerated by using the corespondent [Delphi IDE refactoring command](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Extracting_Resource_String), or with third-party utilities like as [ModelMaker Tools](http://www.modelmakertools.com/articles/hard-coded-strings.html).

Then you can use any available localizer to translate or even internationalize your program. I'd recommend [my Delphi localizer](https://sites.google.com/site/kryvich/localizer) - it's free.

Comment: Kryvich, do you the full source code available for your application? It looks like it will do what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you have two ways

1. Resource-based localization tools (Delphi ITE, Multilizer, ecc.)
2. Database-based localization tools (GetText, TsiLang, ecc.)

The former takes advantage of the Windows resource support, resource loading can be redirected to a different one stored into a DLL when the application is started. The advantages are that whole forms can be localized, including images, colors, control sizes, etc. and not only strings. Moreover, no code change is required. The disadvantages are that end-user localization is not usually possible, and changing language without restarting the application may be trickier. Microsoft applications, including Windows itself, use this technique. It will work with any Delphi libraries that stores strings into resources and dfms properly.

The latter stores strings in an external "database" (it could even be a text file...). The advantage is usually that users can add/modify translations, and switching language on the fly easier. The disadvantages are this technique is more intrusive (it has to hook string loading/display) and may require code changes, tools are usually limited to string localization and don't offer broader control (images, sizes, etc.), and may not work with unknown controls/libraries they could not hook correctly. Usually cross-platform application use this technique because Windows-like resource support is not available on all operating systems.

You should choose the technique that suits you and your application best. Moreover some tools ease the collaboration with an external translator, while others don't. I prefer the resource-based approach because it doesn't require code changes and don't tie me to a given library.

Comment: This answer describes l10n. But i believe the main problem of topicstarter as for now is i18n. Later he would come for l10n stage but for now - "tools for fast find, parcing all pas'es for string constants" - he need i18n tools.

Comment: The OP should adopt the solution the fit best its need from the start. If he uses something alike GetText and modifies his code accordingly and then he finds it does not fit his needs he would have to revert changes and start again. Good libraries already store strings in resourcestrings so no need to parse them. He has to parse its own code to look for embedded strings and move them to constants or better resourcestrings. Good localization tools are able to parse files anyway spotting for strings that need localization. One of common big mistakes is to believe translating strings is enough.

Comment: Since the library he mentions have Russian strings, not English - i conclude it was never intended for i18n and it is not what you call "good library" :-)

Comment: When you move from English to Russian i can name two common obstacles. 1: GUI should be scaled as generally Russian words are longer. 2: English has only single plural form: 1 apple or many apples. And rules are almost the same for any noun. In russian there would be two plural endings here, and they would be different for different word classes. Additionally when you use parametrized strings, like Format functin, you would have to re-order parameters.
I don't remember Spanish, but for  what it has more verb endings than russian, but that relates to tenses and would hardly be affectes by l10n

Comment: THere's really no need to alter the Format() parameters - just use the proper indexes in the format string (which should be stored in a resourcestring....). Anyway you don't have to implement automatic translation - so plural or verbs are not an issue, especially if you don't try to use the same entry for different parts of the application. Keep different string identifiers unless you are sure they are exactly the same. Also that's why tools that let you translate seeing the context are better than those who jusyt give you a list of strings outside their context.

Comment: exactly what i mean by re-ordering here. Reordering inside Format function.

Answer (score 1):

We are using dxgettext (GNUGettext for Delphi and C++ Builder) and Gorm (from the same author). Mind you, most tools require you to use English as the primary language and translate from that only. dxgettext allows other languages but there are bound to be unknown problems with that. Be prepared that internationalizing a large applicatin will be more work than you currently think.