# What is THE way to handle globaly shared Data/objects

Tags: delphi, inheritance, global, share, lazarus

After reading thousands of posts about how bad *Global variables* are, I got back to where I started from.

Here is a contrived example which I hope can explain my situation and my question:

- `TCity`: has a list of **Building**s

  - `TBuilding`: Is part of a **city** | has exact 2 **garages**

    - `TGarage`: Is part of a **Building** | has a List of **Cars**

      - `TCar`: Is part of a **Garage** | Has a Linked List of **Cars**

        - `TCar1`, `TCar2`, `TCar3`: Is Descendant of **TCar**

i have an instance of **TBuilding** which needs to be accessed by every single other Class.

The **TBuilding** Class needs to be accessed by the Cars.

Should I make a global variable for the **TCity** and **TBuilding** instance, or is there anything else I can do ?

I tried to merge the **TCity**, **TBuilding** and **TGarage** classes, but that gives me headaches everytime I try.

Could some experienced people here lead me in the right direction?

I was about to create a *Container Class*, to share the needed instances between units. But after reading lots of posts, I wasn't sure that this was the correct way of dealing with this problem.

What about `resourcestring`s. Should I create a Container with reourcestrings which are shared amongst Classes. For Example if I have about 20 classes where I need the same string every time. The string needs to be translated, so I make a `resourcestring` out of it. Where do I collect such data?

Comment: Why needs ``TCar`` access to ``TBuilding``? Maybe you can decouple your code using events or anonymous methods!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any global variable for what you seem to be trying to achieve.

All you need to do is store reference to parent class instance for each object.

For instance you add another field called City to your `TBuilding` class and upon its creation you set reference to the `TCity` instance to which this building belongs.

```
TBuilding = class(TObject)
private
  FCity: TCity;
protected
  ...
public
  constructor Create(ACity: TCity);
  property City: TCity read FCity write FCity;
end;

...

constructor TBuilding.Create(ACity: TCity);
begin
  inherited;
  FCity := ACity;
end;
```

Then do similar for `TGarage`, and `TCar`.

By doing so you get ability to access Building object from a car object with something like this `Car.Garage.Building`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have a TManager now which holds instances of the Data Class. The Data Class is a Class combined with all of my other Classes except the SubClass like Tcar1, TCar2 etc. I handle the refferencing with constructor injection. now if i add a TConfig instance to my manager which needs to be accessed by all of the other Classes i have i get again a circular dependency or did i do somnething wrong again ?

Comment: What do you mean by _circular dependency_? Can you edit your question in order to show roughly how you implemented your object right now?

Comment: i managed to solve the circular dependency with creating strong and weak dependencies. Howerver i still don't know in which unit i should put resourcestrings that need to be accessed by multiple classes. Should i create a new unit just to hold those resourcestrings ?

Comment: If those resource strings are shared between multiple units then creating a new unit for them and have other units reference to it might be a god approach.  You can find quite a lot of information about resource string in [Is there some advantage in use resourcestring instead of a const string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4292611/3636228) question here on SO.